# uml question - generalization

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

i have a doubt. Imagine that i have three categories: student, worker, student/worker.

the correct is :

```
           ProfissonalArea

    |           |                  |
    |           |                  |
student    worker/student        worker
```

or exists a better way to do that? the problem is that a student can have a work.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does a person have to be associated with *one* category only? That will only force you to enumerate all possible combinations. You would probably be better off with a multi-value field where multiple categories can be specified simultaneously.

If that is not possible, at least use inheritance, so that e.g. the case of a working student will be an implementation of both a worker and a student, rather than a different thing altogether.

Comment: if i understand, what you suggest in the first place is remove the 3 categories and create something like "formationProperties" that has all fields of three categories?

Comment: @user455318: What I disagree with in principle is the `student/worker` case. What if you need to add students with a scholarship? Or people with more than one jobs? Unless it is homework, where you *know* that this is all, solutions that boil down to enumerating all combinations are prone to come back and bite you.

Comment: @user455318: If these are mere categories, with no associated fields, a multi-value field to allow a person to be both a worker and a student is all you need. If these are actually object classes, you should use interfaces and inheritance, so that a WorkingStudent can be used wherever a Worker or a Student are used.

Comment: thanks, you help me to understand the problem. the student/worker no make sense to exists if it can be obtained with student+worker attributes. thanks